# Disenrolled and Disenrollment

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

I'm having trouble finding "disenrolled", "disenrollment", and even "unenrolled" in a dictionary. Are any of these valid words? I'm looking for the noun and verb forms of reversing an enrollment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common term as it relates to college and other course registrations, at least, is to *drop.*  As in:

> I was enrolled in Political Science 420, but I had to drop it because there was too much coursework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm thinking in the context of being enrolled in a program of some sort, like being enrolled in a Medicaid.

Comment: I think "drop" should work fine for that too.  I've heard it used for things like `You'll be dropped from this insurance coverage  90 days after your termination date.`

Comment: I see what you mean. "Drop" can work both ways. Medicaid can drop you, and you can drop Medicaid.